# I deleted my network manager

Tags: networking, network-manager

I was running few terminal commands and ran "purge network-manager" command. And as expected I deleted my network manager and I am unable to access the internet. I searched the internet for a solution and found that the "network manager" file can be downloaded from ubuntu website to another device and copy the file to ubuntu computer. Then we can run the "dpkg -i" command to install the network manager back. I tired to find the network manager file on the website but could not find it as I found many variants(versions) of it. Can somebody point me to the network manager file required for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ? And it would be of great help if you can confirm that the procedure that I am trying is safe and sound.

Thanking you in Advance.

Edit: I am a new to ubuntu. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, you could configure the networking service manually (either using `ifconfig` or by temporarily editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file) and then re-install the necessary package(s) using `apt-get` - that way, you'd be assured of getting the right version and all its dependencies

Comment: Hello steeldriver, Using your method can I connect to internet using Ethernet directly?

Comment: Yes (well, usually via a router rather than "directly"). It should be straightforward if you have a wired ethernet connection - harder but usually doable if you only have wireless.

Comment: I found this trick on the internet, please correct me if anything is wrong with this one. First I connect to ethernet and run "sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces" . Then, at then end of the file I append "allow-hotplug eth0" and "iface eth0 inect dhcp". Then I run "sudo ifdown eth0" and "sudo ifup eth0". This should connect me to the internet. Then I simply install it using apt-get install network-manager... This is what I found in the net. Will this work?

Comment: That *should* work - provided you are connected to a router that will provide you with a valid IP and DNS address. If it does work, remember to re-edit the file once you have got network-manager back.

Comment: Hello steeldriver, I tried the method mentioned by DJCrashdummy below and it worked. Thanks for the info. I am writing this from my Ubuntu machine. Thanks again. CHeers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first please open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), type `uname -i` and then press <kbd>enter</kbd> to see what architecture you are using.

after that use an other machine, go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/network-manager and download the according `.deb`-file at the bottom of the page.

with the file back at the first machine just double-click at the file, and in the window press install.

---

it may be possible that the `network-manager.deb` refuses install because of missing dependencies, than i guess you have to do the same for [network-manager-gnome](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/network-manager-gnome) or what ever dependencies it needs.

but before messing around with too much dependencies it would be better to connect to your network via terminal and [`ifconfig`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/ifconfig.8.html) and then reinstall the network-manager with `sudo apt install network-manager`. but keep in mind, you may have to revert the `ifconfig`-changes and activate the `network-manager`.

Comment: it is most likely that `uname -i` will return `x86_64`, which means you usually need the `amd64`-builds of software.

Comment: yes, you are right. I got x86_64

Comment: Hello DJCrashdummy, I tired to install amd64 deb file and received the following errors. i dont know what to make out of it (Reading database ... 1042252 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack network-manager_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking network-manager (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.1) over (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.1) ...

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager:

 libnl-3-200:i386 (3.2.21-1ubuntu4.1) breaks network-manager (<< 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3~) and is installed.

Comment: Version of network-manager to be configured is 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.1.
 libnl-3-200:amd64 (3.2.21-1ubuntu4.1) breaks network-manager (<< 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3~) and is installed.
 
 Version of network-manager to be configured is 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.1.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager (--install):
 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...

Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ..
.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 network-manager

Comment: Can you please help me out with this.. thanking you

Comment: ahh... damn it! - sorry @Supercooldude283 wrong link, please use the following instead: https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/network-manager **--** also updated the answer.

Comment: Yahoo !! @ DJCrashdummy it worked like a charm. I am writing this message from my Ubuntu. Thanks a lot. Cheers. I had to purge the previous package that you recommended and installed this new one again. But worked like charm.

Comment: By the way a last silly question, I guess I can now delete the .deb file from my Ubuntu machine I guess right? I saved it in Documents folder and installed it from there. Can I delete it now or is it advisable to keep it there ?

Comment: glad to help. **||** you guess right, you can somehow see `.deb`-files as a pendant to `.exe`-installers on windows...